# Python throwing list index out of range error for data generator Tensorflow Keras Functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm working with the Keras Functional API to make an English to Spanish translation program and my first error was RAM overloads from the data being loaded in. I fixed that (or rather, I'm attempting to fix it) by adding a DataGenerator class to only load in batches of 32 data points at a time rather than the full 112k data points. The issue I have is that the code keeps crashing because of a List Index out of Range error and I'm not sure where it's coming from. I know the code for the model itself is good because it compiles properly but when it's about to start training, it crashes. I've tried moving around the code, changing how the generator is loaded in, and I think even changing the dims outputted by the DataGen but it keeps crashing.

Exact error message:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-cad2048bcf92> in <module>
    132 list_ids = sorted(np.load('../input/spa-eng-separated/archive/list_ids.npy'))
    133 train_gen = DataGenerator(list_ids, n_eng, n_es)
--> 134 ED2.train(train_gen, EPOCHS)
    135 
    136 test_string = "hi how are you doing"

<ipython-input-4-5d44382e543b> in train(self, train_gen, epochs)
     48             x=train_gen, # train_gen will return tuple ([encoder_in, decoder_in], decoder_out)
     49             epochs=epochs,
---> 50             verbose = 2#,
     51 #             workers = 6,
     52 #             use_multiprocessing = True

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1061           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1062           model=self,
-> 1063           steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
   1064 
   1065       # Container that configures and calls `tf.keras.Callback`s.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
   1115         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1116         distribution_strategy=ds_context.get_strategy(),
-> 1117         model=model)
   1118 
   1119     strategy = ds_context.get_strategy()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, shuffle, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, model, **kwargs)
    914         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    915         model=model,
--> 916         **kwargs)
    917 
    918   @staticmethod

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, model, **kwargs)
    794           lambda x: model(x, training=False), args=(concrete_x,))
    795 
--> 796     self._first_batch_size = int(nest.flatten(peek)[0].shape[0])
    797 
    798     def _get_dynamic_shape(t):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    885       else:
    886         if self._v2_behavior:
--> 887           return self._dims[key].value
    888         else:
    889           return self._dims[key]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

All I can figure out is that the code is crashing because of something related to the model.fit() and the train generator. Code below.

```py
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import numpy as np

"""
Borrowed code from https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly
(modified some of it but used that site for base)
"""

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
# class DataGenerator():
# tried removing the superclass keras.utils.Sequence

    def __init__(self, list_IDs, n_en, n_es, batch_size=32, shuffle=True):
        # Initializing the generator
        
#         self.dim=dim 
        self.batch_size=batch_size
        self.dim = (32, 51, 53)
#         self.labels=labels
        self.list_id=list_IDs
#         self.n_chan=n_channels
#         self.n_class=n_classes
        self.shuffle=shuffle
        
        self.n_eng = n_en
        self.n_esp = n_es
        
        self.on_epoch_end()
        
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.idx = np.arange(len(self.list_id))
        
        # Makes sure that batches change between epochs
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.idx)
            
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_id)) // self.batch_size) # n_epochs per batch | the // operator divides but turns it into an int as well w/o the explicit int(x) call
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # generate indices of bat
        idxs = self.idx[(idx*self.batch_size):((idx+1)*self.batch_size)]
    
        temp_idx = [self.list_id[k] for k in idxs]
        
        enc, d_in, d_out = self.__data_generation(temp_idx) 
        
        return ([enc, d_in], d_out)
    
    def __data_generation(self, temp_ids):
            
        """
        The way this will work is basically by loading in the data at the id in a saved np file
        Then we'll read it in as the 2d matrix (a list of tensors where each tensor is a list of indices/values) and transform it into a 3d matrix in the style of the sep_data method
        """
        
#         en = np.empty((self.bat, *self.dim, self.n_chan))
#         es = np.empty((self.bat, *self.dim, self.n_chan))
        en = []
        es = []
        
        # data gen
        for i, ID in enumerate(temp_ids):
            # load samples
            en.append(np.load('../input/spa-eng-separated/archive/' + str(ID) + '_en.npy'))
            es.append(np.load('../input/spa-eng-separated/archive/' + str(ID) + '_es.npy'))
            
        enc_in = np.ndarray([])
        dec_in = np.ndarray([])
        dec_out = np.ndarray([])
        for i, x in enumerate(en):
            e_temp, d_temp, o_temp = sep_data(en[i], es[i], self.n_eng, self.n_esp)

            np.append(enc_in, e_temp)
            np.append(dec_in, d_temp)
            np.append(dec_out, o_temp)
            # separating the data into an encoder inp, decoder inp, decoder out

        enc_in.astype('int')
        dec_in.astype('int')
        dec_out.astype('int')

        return enc_in, dec_in, dec_out

import tensorflow.keras as keras
import keras.layers as layers
import numpy as np

class EnDe2():
    def __init__(self, inp_size, targ_size, embedding_dim, units, bat, input_vocab, target_vocab):
        
        self.bat_size = bat
        
        # input -> encoder embedding -> encoder GRU -> 
        # save states -> decoder input -> decoder GRU w encoder states -> 
        # decoder LSTM -> dense w softmax activ
        
        
        enc_in = layers.Input(shape=(None,))
#         print(input_vocab, embedding_dim)
        enc_out = layers.Embedding(input_dim=input_vocab+1, output_dim=embedding_dim//2)(enc_in)
        enc_out, state = layers.GRU(units//2, 
                                    return_state=True,
                                    recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')(enc_out)

        dec_in = layers.Input(shape=(None,))
#         print(target_vocab, embedding_dim
        dec_out = layers.Embedding(input_dim=target_vocab+1, output_dim=embedding_dim//2)(dec_in)
        dec_out = layers.GRU(units//2)(dec_out, initial_state=state)
        dec_out = layers.Dense(targ_size, activation='softmax')(dec_out)
        
        self.model = keras.models.Model([enc_in, dec_in], dec_out)
        
        self.model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
        self.model.summary()
        
    def train(self, train_gen, epochs):
        self.model.compile(
            optimizer="rmsprop", 
            loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
            metrics=["accuracy"]
        )
#         self.model.fit(
#             [e, d_in],
#             d_out,
#             batch_size=self.bat_size,
#             epochs=epochs,
#             validation_split=0.2, 
#         )
    
        self.model.fit(
            x=train_gen, # train_gen will return tuple ([encoder_in, decoder_in], decoder_out)
            epochs=epochs, 
#             verbose = 2#,
            workers = 6,
            use_multiprocessing = True
            
        )
    
#         self.model.fit_generator(
#             generator=train_gen, 
#             validation_data=eval_gen, 
#             use_multiprocessing=True,
#             workers=6
#         )

        self.model.save("./s2s")
```

I'm trying to use a Seq2Seq model (Encoder Decoder) except with words rather than the base letters. Sorry if the code above is hard to read - here's a (link)[https://www.kaggle.com/aaravgupta4/engtospanish-translation/edit?rvi=1] to the online notebook that I'm using to run the code (and has it divided into cells; https://www.kaggle.com/aaravgupta4/engtospanish-translation/edit?rvi=1).

My guess is that the superclass (keras.utils.Sequence) needs the DataGenerator child class to have a dims attribute but I couldn't find anything in the docs for it and on top of that, I don't remember adding a dims variable to the DataGenerator class helping.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: is `traing_gen[0]` returning the correct result?

Comment: Hi krxat! I just checked the code for train_gen (specifically the __getitem__ function) and apparently it's returning ([int, int], int) rather than arrays which might be part of the issue (.shape is an attribute for arrays so basically calling int.shape would throw an error). I'll look through my data generation code and add an update about the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Great, Also, it should return `(([batch_size, ...], [batch_size, ...]), [batch_size, ...])`. The input should be a tuple, not array.

Comment: Also, why are you converting them into `int` using `astype('int')`. I think, and I could be wrong but it is always best to use `float32` as your input to the model.

Comment: Yeah I think it returns those dimensions - I just meant that it was returning numbers in those slots rather than arrays/lists. As for the `astype('int')`, I think I was running into an error earlier about something with `float64`s. I removed the `astype('int')` and I also think I got rid of the `dims` error! It seems like the reason that I was getting `int` back rather than `ndarray` was because I was using `np.append` incorrectly. I think I was doing `np.append(old_arr, val)` rather than `new = np.append(old, val)` so the append arrays weren't being saved.

Comment: is your problem solved now?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Thank you!

Comment: NIce. Close the issue if it is resolved :')